# show data in array grouped by week

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I already sort out my array date wise.I have array start index date and last index date.now in want to show my array with sub array grouped by week. I am using CodeIgniter.

My controller code is

```
public function test()
{
    if($details_sort= $this->api_model->testw())
    {
        $msg = "OK";

        $details=$details_sort;

        $first = reset($details);
        $last = end($details);

        $result = array($first['date'], $last['date']);

        $start_date=$first['date'];
        $last_date=$last['date'];

    }
    else
        $msg = "ERROR";

        $output = array(
            'msg' => $msg,
            'details' => $details,
            '1st' => $start_date,
            'last' => $last_date
        );

        jsonOutput($output);
    }
```

My current output is

```
{
    "msg":"OK",
    "details":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "score":"233",
            "user_id":"4",
            "date":"2014-02-03 00:00:00",

        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "score":"1256",
            "user_id":"5",
            "date":"2014-02-05 00:00:00",

        },
        {
            "id":"4",
            "score":"123",
            "user_id":"7",
            "date":"2014-03-04 00:00:00",

        },
        {
            "id":"3",
            "score":"100",
            "user_id":"6",
            "date":"2014-03-08 00:00:00",

        },
        {
            "id":"5",
            "score":"8",
            "user_id":"2",
            "date":"2014-03-13 00:00:00",
"
        }
    ],
    "1st":"2014-02-03 00:00:00",
    "last":"2014-03-13 00:00:00"
}
```

But I want to show my output like as

```
{
    "msg":"OK",
    "details":[
                "week 1":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "score":"233",
                        "user_id":"4",
                        "date":"2014-02-03 00:00:00",

                    },
                "week 2":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "score":"233",
                        "user_id":"4",
                        "date":"2014-02-03 00:00:00",

                    },

    ],
    "1st":"2014-02-03 00:00:00",
    "last":"2014-03-13 00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i show my array data separately that mean grouped by week .my first date and last date have more week so i want to show weekly data @DoXicK

Comment: This is an insufficiently clear [mcve]. Contributors cannot confidently answer and curators cannot determine the desired/correct result.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses the data from ***My current output is*** submitted above, and demonstrates how to convert that into weekly arrays for details

```
<?php

// Take your submitted output
$jsonData = '{"msg":"OK","details":[{ "id":"1","score":"233","user_id":"4", "date":"2014-02-03 00:00:00"}, { "id":"2", "score":"1256","user_id":"5", "date":"2014-02-05 00:00:00"},{"id":"4", "score":"123", "user_id":"7", "date":"2014-03-04 00:00:00"},{ "id":"3", "score":"100", "user_id":"6", "date":"2014-03-08 00:00:00"},{ "id":"5", "score":"8", "user_id":"2", "date":"2014-03-13 00:00:00"}], "1st":"2014-02-03 00:00:00", "last":"2014-03-13 00:00:00"}';
// and convert it to an array
$origArray=json_decode($jsonData);

// We will want an array to hold data
$weeklyDetails = array();

// Lets loop through each of your details
foreach ($origArray->details as $detail){
    // and get the week number
    $weekNo=date("W", strtotime($detail->date));

    // and if we don't already have an array for that week
    if (! array_key_exists("week $weekNo", $weeklyDetails) ){
        //create it
        $weeklyDetails["week $weekNo"] = array();
    } 
    // lets push the detail into that week
    array_push($weeklyDetails["week $weekNo"], $detail);
}

// Assign the new details
$origArray->details = $weeklyDetails;

// Convert back to json
$jsonData = json_encode($origArray);

// print it out.
print($jsonData);
```

This will provide the following output:

```
{
  "msg": "OK",
  "details": {
    "week 06": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "score": "233",
        "user_id": "4",
        "date": "2014-02-03 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "score": "1256",
        "user_id": "5",
        "date": "2014-02-05 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "week 10": [
      {
        "id": "4",
        "score": "123",
        "user_id": "7",
        "date": "2014-03-04 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "score": "100",
        "user_id": "6",
        "date": "2014-03-08 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "week 11": [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "score": "8",
        "user_id": "2",
        "date": "2014-03-13 00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "1st": "2014-02-03 00:00:00",
  "last": "2014-03-13 00:00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't have datasource and I can not try this code but if my assumptions are correct try this script..

```
<?php 
public function test()
{
    $monthly = "";
    if ($details_sort = $this->api_model->testw()) {
        $msg = "OK";
        $detailsForWeek = array();
        foreach($details_sort as $dsWeek){
            $detailsForWeek[] = array('week' => $dsWeek);
        }
        $details = $detailsForWeek;
        $first = reset($details_sort);
        $last = end($details_sort);
        $result = array($first['date'], $last['date']);
        $start_date=$first['date'];
        $last_date=$last['date'];
    } else 
        $msg = "ERROR";

    $output = array(
        'msg' => $msg,
        'details' => $details,
        '1st' => $start_date,
        'last' => $last_date
    );
}
```

Comment: how you calculate that how many weeks are 2014-02-03 00:00:00 To 2014-03-13 00:00:00